# Returning values of different columns with UNIQUE

Tags: excel, duplicates, unique

So I have returned unique values from another sheet with =UNIQUE('sheet1'!A:A) and am now trying to also return values from one of those rows that are in different columns.

This is the kind of sheet I draw unique vehicles from, the sheet can be changed dynamically to fit new data/changed data, hence why I want to bring the unique values

| A vehicle | B owner | C ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bike | Justin | 3 |
| Bike | Justin | 3 |
| Bike | Justin | 3 |
| Car | Peter | 6 |
| Car | Peter | 6 |
| Car | Peter | 6 |
| Car | Peter | 6 |
| Boat | John | 12 |
| Boat | John | 12 |
| Boat | John | 12 |
| Boat | John | 12 |
| Boat | John | 12 |

From here with UNIQUE IT BECOMES

| A vehicle |
| --- |
| Bike |
| Car |
| Boat |

How do I bring information to other columns as the UNIQUE from other columns that are in the same row as the information from the other sheet?

I've tried =IF(A2='sheet1'!A:A, 'sheet1'!B, ""), but it only returns me a #SPILL!
I do not want to use the excels own "remove duplicates" option as that is not very dynamic for if the data in the other sheet changes

The end result I am looking for is

| A vehicle | B owner |
| --- | --- |
| Bike | 3 |
| Car | 6 |
| Boat | 12 |

Comment: Is there any possibility to have same type card with different ID?

Comment: @Harun24hr no there isn't but the ID can be empty

Comment: In case of empty what will be result? Empty will be treated as separate unique? Or you want as unique which have id?

Comment: @harun24hr it is fine for empty data to remain empty in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the CHOOSE function to create an array with the UNIQUE function

Enter this formula using CHOOSE to create an array with the two columns.

```
=CHOOSE({1,2},A2:A13,C2:C13)
```

| A vehicle | C ID |
| --- | --- |
| Bike | 3 |
| Bike | 3 |
| Bike | 3 |
| Car | 6 |
| Car | 6 |
| Car | 6 |
| Car | 6 |
| Boat | 12 |
| Boat | 12 |
| Boat | 12 |
| Boat | 12 |
| Boat | 12 |

Then wrap the formula in the UNIQUE function.

```
=UNIQUE(CHOOSE({1,2},A2:A13,C2:C13))
```

| A vehicle | C ID |
| --- | --- |
| Bike | 3 |
| Car | 6 |
| Boat | 12 |

[image: Data and Formula in Excel]

A new function **CHOOSECOLS** was introduced in September 2022, which can be used to make the formula more readable.

**CHOOSECOLS** takes a range/array as an input followed by the columns to be returned.

```
=UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(A1:C13,1,3))
```

Comment: If I use this formula it only returns me the first array containing the unique vehicles but does not return the column with ID's

Comment: Try just the CHOOSE formula `=CHOOSE({1,2},A2:A13,C2:C13)` to experiment and see what is returned.  The first part of the formula needs to use the **{ }** brackets.

Comment: It returns all the vehicles from the vehicle list without uniques

Comment: =UNIQUE(CHOOSE({1,2}; A1:A13; C1:C13))

Comment: as a side note I need to use ; instead of , to split the formulas

Comment: There are two alternates. Store the 1 and 2 values in other cells and then refer to them in the CHOOSE formula `=CHOOSE(E1:F1;A2:A13;C2:C13)`. Or try a back slash \ as the separator `=CHOOSE({1\2};A2:A13;C2:C13)`.